# odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: account.report_invoice_with_payments

Tags: odoo

I try to customize report of invoice with payments, but can't find the file xml in addons path , also i have this error :

```
raise ValueError('External ID not found in the system: %s' % xmlid)
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "External ID not found in the system:  account.report_invoice_with_payments" while parsing None:182, near
<data inherit_id=" account.report_invoice_with_payments">
            <!--EDIT Quantity column: print one value centred-->
            <xpath expr="//table[@class='table table-condensed']//tbody//tr//td[2]" position="replace">
            </xpath>
        </data>
2019-01-23 14:14:49,956 5585 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a space in the ID `inherit_id="_SPACE_account.report_invoice_with_payments"`. You have to remove that: `inherit_id="account.report_invoice_with_payments"`

And make sure that your module/app is depending on `account`.